# How to download video from arte+7, arte-tv and similar sites?

Tags: flash, tv, downloaders

[Arte tv](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.arte.tv/&ei=ahhJUMbNMajC0QWp94DoCQ&usg=AFQjCNGUJiH1Cy-ng80madKLgmVaSFJsvQ&sig2=_Am-Xr_iZD38BbzWJSs-nQ) has a [website called arte+7](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQjBAwAg&url=http://videos.arte.tv/&ei=ahhJUMbNMajC0QWp94DoCQ&usg=AFQjCNGVcBlrxO0sLyNObolMb4UkLpn3Ew&sig2=TYyZRbMF5wZJfon4N0pwiA) where some videos are provided for a period of time. But these are not as easy to download as those on youtube and other such websites.

Is there a program that can do that?

Comment: it is NOT true that this question already has an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11211/how-to-download-flash-streaming-videos-from-sites-like-youtube-dailymotion-v)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the evolution of the website, some of these solutions may stop working from time to time.

### A cross-platform solution:

Lately, Arte has posted on its [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/ARTEplus7/videos) *some* of the videos. (On that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video).)

### Another cross-platform solution:

[A userscript](https://github.com/GuGuss/ARTE-7-Playground) does the trick. Can be used with Greasemonkey in Firefox and Tampermonkey in Chrome - so this is a cross-platform solution.

It will display download option under the video screen.

[image]

After installing Greasemonkey, click [here](https://github.com/GuGuss/ARTE-7-Playground/raw/master/arte-downloader.user.js) to install the script.

If that stops working, look for an updated version.

---

### Videoob

It is the 'video capability' of the powerful and much larger tool [Weboob](http://weboob.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install weboob weboob-qt
```

**Videoob** is **not limited to arte tv.**

To just **search and watch the video (in a rather limited integrated video player)**, you can use **Qvideoob**, the qt frontend of `videoob`.

[image]

[image]

(The player window shows the url of the video, which can be copied and used in an external player - see below.)

From there you can update and add new 'backends' (tv stations and such). Backends > Add. (The **Weboob backends configuration tool** can also be launched separately from a launcher like Dash.)

[image]

To **download**:

Open terminal and run `videoob`. You will see this

`videoob>`

Type `help` to see more options.

Type `search TERM`  in order to find titles, like for example

```
videoob> search republique
```

then, after getting a list of titles just type, `download NUMBER` to download a certain title according to its number (it  should look like so: `videoob:/search> download 1`). The download goes to `~/`.

I use a desktop file to launch the terminal directly with that:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/TV-download.desktop
```

with

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=AudioVideo;
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'videoob' --profile=hold
Icon=qvideoob
Name=TV France (search, then download)
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;System;
```

Instead of downloading with `wget` in terminal, you may watch the video in an external player like **mpv** (with `mpv <url>`) or **SMPlayer** (*Open-URL*). To get the video url use `info` instead of `download` and the address will appear after `url:`

[image]

Also, the url of the video is displayed in the window of the Qvideoob integrated player as seen above.

---

### **Qarte**

([Source](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=861411&p=1)) - Also, thanks to [Carl](https://askubuntu.com/users/451912/carl) for posting an answer on Qarte in September 2015 on the new Qarte versions that work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vincent-vandevyvre/vvv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qarte
```

To download the deb, [here](http://www.oqapy.eu/download?lang=en).

[image]

Qarte has a second part dedicated to [arte live web](http://liveweb.arte.tv/)

[image]

---

A very good tool is [Captvty](http://captvty.fr/) from Windows: to install that under Wine, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/848511/47206) separate post; installing it may take some time, but it may be very useful in that it **displays all available titles** for many stations without the need (and the possibility) to search.

[image]

---

Comment: What does it mean that "Qarte does not have any download files registered with Launchpad"? Does it mean the code might be less safe, cuz not officially Launchpad-reviewed or sth like that?

Comment: thx for the extra info! (though this doesn't really answer my Launchpad-related question; I'm just curious and don't understand the repercussions of the "no registered downloads"-statement; googling flooded me with Launchpad entries and mirrors, but no discussions or explanations of that statement).

Answer (score 7):

Arte.tv website has been completly rewritten in March 2013...
Probably old scripts and hacks have not updated their code.

I have created a small standalone php webpage that allow you to download, without any software or account any Arte+7 videos as a MP4 file , just go there: http://floriancrouzat.net/arte/ and paste your Arte+7 URL.
If you liked it, either recommend the page or leave me a comment, it's always a pleasure ;)
-- Florian

Comment: it seems Qarte works again too.

Answer (score 5):

There is qarte (http://www.oqapy.eu/download?lang=en), but you still need to be in a country where you can watch Arte.

There is a how-to in French here :
http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/qarte

Comment: i have now un-deleted an older (formerly definitive) answer of mine [(here)](http://askubuntu.com/a/184904/47206), on Qarte: but that had stopped working as of april 2013 and so I switched to different solutions. It seems to work again now. Great.

Comment: thanks for the links on the updated versions. I have undeleted my older poste, updated the links according to your answer, and merged it with my newer post on the userscript

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it:

- GO TO http://www.arte.tv/guide/fr/, choose the desired video link and open it in browser
- click “View Page Source”
- in source, search for link that contains `PLUS7` and `ALL.json`
- copy that link *but don't remove* the string `player/` from it
- open it in browser
- in that page, search for `.MP4` or `HD -` (if you want high-definition) or `version` for language.

The first URL found is something like that:
http://arte.tv/papi/tvguide/videos/stream/player/F/053366-002_PLUS7-F/ALL/ALL.json

There are several `HBBTV.mp4`, one for each version. Look for the language version of mp4 which you would prefer. There are blocks like:

```js
"HTTP_MP4_EQ_1":{"quality":"MD - 400p","width":720,"height":406,"mediaType":"mp4","mimeType":"video/mp4","bitrate":1500,"url":"http://artestras.vo.llnwd.net/v2/am/HBBTV/053366-002-A_EQ_2_VF-STF_01749068_MP4-1500_AMM-HBBTV.mp4","videoFormat":"HBBTV","versionProg":"1","versionCode":"VF-STF","versionLibelle":"VF","versionShortLibelle":"VF","VQU":"EQ"},
```

They are all written on one line, so copy-pasting to a text editor helps. It becomes possible to use new lines where the closing brackets are, and thus to separate the versions. Warning: there are also versions other than mp4 files.

Once you have found the link you want, copy this new link to browser (e. g. Firefox) and *wait if necessary*. When you see the player, right-click on it and choose "save video as".

Thanks to Nikola for the first part of this answer.

Comment: " search for HBBTV.MP4" didn't work when I tried it.  I would suggest at that stage searching for part that starts with  `http://` and ends with `.mp4`.

Comment: instead of  search for `HBBTV.MP4` it should be `HBBTV_MP4`, I have edited your answer.

Comment: this is useful in order to get the subtitled video if needed

Answer (score 1):

You could try *my python script*. It is an interactive menu based application. Still some work to be finished. But mostly working

Go and get it at https://github.com/solsticedhiver/arteVIDEOS

But most arte+7 videos are available on [*youtube*](https://www.youtube.com/user/ARTE) nowadays so *any youtube downloader* can get you what you want most of the time.