# How do I stream Arte TV live?

Tags: streaming, totem

I am trying to stream Arte TV live and cannot find the correct streaming flux address.

[I use Totem with the specific Arte streaming codec and/or plugin downloaded and installed from the Ubuntu Soft Center.]

I did run some queries here and there (Google and askubuntu) and found only [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184893/how-to-download-video-from-arte7-and-arte-tv-related-sites) as the closest thing to what I am looking for. Generally speaking apart from the fact that a lot of TV and radio stations passively limit the amount of streaming by users, I know that Arte is only available in France and Germany. I use Selektor to proxy in from servers geolocalized in Germany.

Can someone help me find the correct streaming address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my little python script at https://github.com/solsticedhiver/arteVIDEOS

It will give you the stream url given the language you have choosen and the quality.

It's http://frlive.artestras.cshls.lldns.net/artestras/frlive/frlive.m3u8 but beware that totem is not able to play it. Only sound. I have not look into this. A codec issue or the m3u8 thing...

Comment: Thanks solsTiCe ! I looked at your Readme and you mention that one needs `python2.7` (but not  `python3`) and `beautifulsoup` v 3.2.1. ...  On the former I have both python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.0 installed. My default is 2.7.6 (i.e. this is what runs if I just type `python` on the cmd line), so I suppose that's that. Please correct me if I am wrong.  On the latter, did you mean `python-beautifulsoup`the html parser for Python ?

Comment: Actually the streaming address you just gave me is fine in `totem 3.10.1` supplemented with `totem-plugin-arte 3.2.1-2ubuntu0.14.04.2`....... In French amazingly there doesn't seem to be any streaming quality prbm at all (no jitter, no sound degradation)..... The only thing is: it's in French ! .........  So I changed it to  http://delive.artestras.cshls.lldns.net/artestras/delive/delive.m3u8 but there the streaming quality is bad to the point of not having sound (except for the very beginning of the streaming session), only image with a lot of jitter all the time. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know. Try vlc ? IT seems to work here. Change your proxy/VPN ?

Comment: Thanks again. `VLC` gives acceptable results with very minor jitter issues. `totem` in my present configuration seems only to be good for Arte+7 video viewing. Too bad because `totem` is my preferred package.

Comment: FYI: I filed bug 752318 (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752318) about totem's "Image jitter and no sound when streaming H.264" as it seems the 3.10.1 version of totem does not handle that well.